# Pioneers building villages challenge: why my linked list implementation gives wrong output?

Tags: python, linked-list

I am trying to solve the following code challenge:

### Challenge description

There are a given number of *pioneers* who can build *villages*. These villages are built on a straight line, and will have a certain order, from left to right. At the very start there are no villages. Once a pioneer has built a village, that village is forever their property, and the pioneer will *reside* at that village until they move to another one.

The input defines a series of operations, which each specify a pioneer (identified by their 0-based index) and an *action* for that pioneer:

- Action "build": the given pioneer builds a new village at the immediate right of where they currently reside, or if the pioneer has no residence yet, it will become the leftmost village. If there is already a village at the immediate right of the pioneer's residence, then the new village will be inserted between the pioneer's current residence and that next village.

  After this operation, the new village becomes the residence of the building pioneer.
- Action "move": the given pioneer simply moves their residence to the next village. If there's no next village, the pioneer remains where they are now.

The program must output the owners of the built villages in their order from left to right, taking into account all the actions specified in the input.

#### Input format

First line has two numbers separate by a space: the number of pioneers and the number of actions

Per action the input has a line with two parts separated by space: a pioneer number and the type of action ("build" or "move")

#### Output format

The first line in the output must give the number of villages

For each village (in their proper order), the output should have a separate line with the index of the pioneer that owns the corresponding village.

#### Example

Input:

```
2 4
0 build
1 build
1 move
1 build
```

Expected output:

```
3
1
0
1
```

The example has two pioneers (0 and 1). Pioneer 0 creates the first village. Pioneer 1 creates a village that is inserted to the left of that village and then moves to the other village. Finally pioneer 1 creates a village to the right of that village.

### My approach

I used a linked list data structure for the villages.

Here is my code:

```
class Village:
    def __init__(self, owner=None):
        self.owner = owner
        self.next = None

class Pioneer:
    def __init__(self, position):
        self.position = None

    def main():
       k, n = map(int, input().split())
    
       pioneers = [Pioneer(i) for i in range(k)]

       starting_village = Village()
       current_village = starting_village

       villages = [starting_village]

        for i in range(n):
            pioneer, action = map(str, input().split())

            if action == "move":
                if current_village.next is not None:
                    current_village = current_village.next
                pioneers[int(pioneer)].position = current_village
    
            elif action == "build":
                new_village = Village(owner=pioneer)
                if current_village.next is not None:
                    new_village.next = current_village.next
                current_village.next = new_village
                pioneers[int(pioneer)].position = new_village
                villages.append(new_village)

        m = len(villages) - 1
        print(m)

        current_village = starting_village.next
        while current_village is not None:
            print(current_village.owner)
            current_village = current_village.next

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

#### Problem

For the example input my code outputs:

```
3 1 1 0
```

...which is evidently not the expected output. I don't understand where it goes wrong. What is my mistake?

Comment: Please quote the literal description of this code challenge. Currently you're just dumping the code on us and at the end speak of villages and pioneers as if we know what you are talking about. There is also no explanation of the input format, nor what the meaning is of the output.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. I've revised the text again.

Comment: I completely rewrote your question. Please check if this correctly reflects the case.

Comment: Thank you...! I'll use it like this when I ask questions from now on. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you use `current_village` to determine what will be the position and insertion point for the action, no matter what the position is of the involved *pioneer*. Instead, you need to work with the village where the current pioneer is at. This is not necessarily the same village for each of the pioneers, so working with one `current_village` is not going to work correctly.

Another issue in your code is that the `position` attribute is not initialised to the dummy village that you create at the start.

Here is how I would correct your code:

```
class Village:
    def __init__(self, owner=None):
        self.owner = owner
        self.next = None
    
class Pioneer:
    def __init__(self, id, position):
        self.id = id              # distinquish id and position
        self.position = position  # initialise with argument

def main():
    k, n = map(int, input().split())

    starting_village = Village()
    num_villages = 0  # Instead of a list of villages, just track a count of them

    # Initialise the pioneers to be at the starting village
    pioneers = [Pioneer(i, starting_village) for i in range(k)]

    for i in range(n):
        pioneerstr, action = input().split()
        pioneer = pioneers[int(pioneerstr)]  # Get the pioneer instance

        # Use the village where the selected pioneer is at
        if action == "move":
            if pioneer.position.next is not None:
                pioneer.position = pioneer.position.next

        elif action == "build":
            new_village = Village(owner=pioneer)
            new_village.next = pioneer.position.next
            pioneer.position.next = new_village
            pioneer.position = new_village
            num_villages += 1

    print(num_villages)

    current_village = starting_village.next
    while current_village is not None:
        print(current_village.owner.id)
        current_village = current_village.next

        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It's completely resolved.. I'll have to be careful in my way of thinking...